# Exported shapekeys to unity don't play correctly

Tags: animation, export, unity, shape-keys, .fbx

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this

I select all relevant parts of the mesh and armature etc and export to FBX 7.4 for use in Unity3d
The model itself displays fine and so does the armature animations but the shapekeys come out really weird.

Any ideas or do you need more info?

Comment: I highly doubt you will get good answers here on a unity problem. Maybe try also asking this on the Game Development Stack Exchange.

Comment: @HenrikD well this seems to be an export problem so would be an issue in blender, not unity. I will try your suggestion